# CSS - Move menu to top on hover

Tags: css

I have a menu that is needed to move an item to top on hover, but it doesn't work. Here is what I do.

```
.menu li{
    display: inline-block;      
}    

.menu li a{
    display: block; 
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;   

}

.menu li a:hover{
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-bottom-width: 10px;
}
```

```
<li class="active">                             
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li>                                
    <a href="#">About</a>
</li>               
<li>                                
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Code is not completed, it would be better post a Demo

Comment: What do you mean 'to top'? To the top of what?

Comment: Move to top about 5px from another menu items.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/26MLv/

One possible solution:

```
.menu li{
    display: inline;      
}    

.menu li a{
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;   
    margin:0;
    background-color:#cecece;

}

.menu li a:hover{
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-bottom-width: 10px;
}
```